# Trying to mount Windows partition - get Failed to mount: <path> is a directory

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

I'm trying to mount a Windows partition. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB drive, and want to mount the internal hard drive of the laptop it's connected to, which has Windows 7 installed. I typed:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /media/windows /dev/sda3
```

I got a couple of error messages saying:

```
Error opening: '/media/windows' is a directory
Failed to mount: '/meda/windows' is a directory
```

I just did this successfully on a different Windows PC last night. I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard form of the mount command, is: `mount -t type device dir`. You've got the order of the directory and the device switched in your command. Your command should be:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /media/windows
```

Comment: great!  I'm an idiot!  Thank you.  Some days I just wonder why i got out of bed at all....you're awesome for 2 reasons.

Comment: Sorry...reason 1 - you answered my question.  Reason 2 - you didn't openly smack me around while doing it!